# Omnet++ "Imported ned type not found"

Tags: omnet++

I'm having an issue where I am trying to import inet.node.inet.StandardHost in Omnet++ but I keep receiving the error "imported NED type not found".

I've already selected inet in project references which is what I had thought the issue was, but it still is giving me the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the INET project actually open?

Comment: The inet project wasn't open. My mistake. Thank you